# Java's own equals method works incorrectly in my code

Tags: java, equals

I am writing a program and in some of the code I write, I have to compare the `ID` of the object I have and the `ID` of the objects in the list where that object is located. But `equals ()` method doesn't work correctly. When I debug, the part that should return `true` returns `false` because the if statement is not working. The `this` object and the object I have are in the picture. Can you please tell me what I did wrong? If you need it, I upload it to github because the codes in my project are long. You can download it from there.

Github Project Link: https://github.com/rootroxox/Error

The part that equals method works incorrectly:

```
case "TransferCargo" -> {
                    System.out.println("Readed Command: "+data);
                    String vehicleID = datas[1];
                    int distance = Integer.parseInt(datas[2]);
                    int load = Integer.parseInt(datas[3]);

                    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicleList) {
                        System.out.println(vehicleID+" "+vehicle.getId());
                        if (vehicle.getId().equals(vehicleID)) {  ------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>> When vehicle.getID() = S00120 and vehicleID = S00120, equals method returns  false...
                            switch (vehicle.getType()) {
                                case "Plane":
                                    for (Plane plane : planeList) {
                                        if (plane.getCrewMembers().size() >= 3 && plane.getPilot() != null) {
                                            int maxLoad = (plane.getMotorCount() + plane.getCrewMembers().size() + 2) * 10;
                                            int maxDistance = (plane.getFuel()) / (((plane.getWeight() + load) / 10) + (plane.getMotorCount() / 2));
                                            if (distance <= maxDistance && load <= maxLoad && plane.getFuel() >= plane.getFuel() - distance) {
                                                plane.setFuelAmount(plane.getFuel() - distance);
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Does NOT Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Truck":
                                    for (Truck truck : truckList) {
                                        if (truck.getDriver() != null){
                                            int maxLoad = ((truck.getEngineVolume()/1000)+(truck.getTorque()/100))*3;
                                            int maxDistance = truck.getFuel()*10/(((load+truck.getWeight())/30)+truck.getEngineVolume()/2000);
                                            if (distance <= maxDistance && load <= maxLoad && truck.getFuel() >= truck.getFuel() - distance) {
                                                truck.setFuelAmount(truck.getFuel() - distance);
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Does NOT Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Ship":
                                    for (Ship ship : shipList) {
                                        if (ship.getCaptain() != null && ship.getCrewMembers().size() >= 5){
                                            int maxLoad = ((ship.getEngineOutput()/1000)+ship.getCrewMembers().size())*15;
                                            int maxDistance = ship.getFuel()*20/(((load+ship.getWeight())/100)+(ship.getEngineOutput()/10000));
                                            if (distance <= maxDistance && load <= maxLoad && ship.getFuel() >= ship.getFuel() - distance) {
                                                ship.setFuelAmount(ship.getFuel() - distance);
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                System.out.println("Cargo Mission Does NOT Accomplished by " + vehicleID);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Post code, not images. Post the smallest possible amount of code needed to show you issue.

Answer (score 3):

## Override `equals`

You need to implement [`Object::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in your own class. Otherwise Java defaults to implementing `equals` as merely a comparison of identity (are the two references pointing to the very same object, the same chunk of memory).

When overriding `equals` to provide your own logic for comparison, always implement `hashCode` as well. Your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) can generate this code for you, but you need the decide which member fields to compare in deciding equality.

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Example:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Invoice
{
    private List < LineItem > lineItems;
    private LocalDate invoiceDate;
    private Integer invoiceNumber;

    public Invoice ( List < LineItem > lineItems , LocalDate invoiceDate , Integer invoiceNumber )
    {
        this.lineItems = new ArrayList < LineItem >( lineItems );  // Shallow copy of the collection, for defensive programming.
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }


    public List < LineItem > getLineItems ( ) { return List.copyOf( this.lineItems ) ; }  // Shallow copy of the collection, for defensive programming.

    public void setLineItems ( List < LineItem > lineItems ) { this.lineItems = new ArrayList < LineItem >( lineItems ); }  // Shallow copy of the collection, for defensive programming.

    public LocalDate getInvoiceDate ( ) { return this.invoiceDate; }

    public void setInvoiceDate ( LocalDate invoiceDate ) { this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate; }

    public Integer getInvoiceNumber ( ) { return this.invoiceNumber; }

    public void setInvoiceNumber ( Integer invoiceNumber ) { this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Invoice invoice = ( Invoice ) o;
        return getInvoiceNumber().equals( invoice.getInvoiceNumber() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getInvoiceNumber() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Invoice{ " +
                "lineItems=" + lineItems +
                " | invoiceDate=" + invoiceDate +
                " | invoiceNumber=" + invoiceNumber +
                " }";
    }
}
```

### Records

The new [records feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) coming to Java makes this easier.

A record in Java is a special kind of class that is meant to be mainly an immutable data carrier. A record provides by default an implementation of `equals` that compares the value of each and every member field.

A record also provides implementations of `hashCode`, `toString`, [accessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method), and constructor.

Here is an example, a `record` class of `Appointment`. We merely declare the member fields after the name of the class. Notice that we can write as few as *zero* lines of code within the curly braces of this class definition.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.*;

public record Appointment(String description , LocalDateTime start , ZoneId timeZone , Duration duration)
{
}
```

Use that record class. We create two similar instances of `Appointment` where only the year differs.

```java
Appointment appointment1 =
        new Appointment(
                "Acupuncture" ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 ) ,
                ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ,
                Duration.ofMinutes( 90 )
        );
// Similar, but change the year.
Appointment appointment2 =
        new Appointment(
                "Acupuncture" ,
                LocalDateTime.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 , 15 , 30 , 0 ) ,
                ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ,
                Duration.ofMinutes( 90 )
        );

boolean appointmentsAreEqual = appointment1.equals( appointment2 );
System.out.println( "appointmentsAreEqual = " + appointmentsAreEqual );
```

When run:

> appointmentsAreEqual = false